# tikz preventing my thesis from compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf

What could be wrong with this code? Can't compile.

```latex
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=green!20, 
    text height=2em, text badly centered, node distance=4cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]
\begin{figure}[H]    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (Solve) {Find solution of Transfer Function (TF)};
    \node [cloud, left of=Solve, node distance=6cm] (start) {START};
    \node [block, below of=Solve] (identify) {Identify climatic conditions};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (SolveT) {Iterate TF in MATLAB};
    \node [block, right of=SolveT, node distance=5cm] (Experiment) {Run Experiment};
    \node [block, below of=SolveT, node distance=2cm] (Compare) {Compare predicted vs experimental};
    \node [block, below of=Compare] (Calibrate) {Calibrate by MATLAB regression leaner};
    \node [block, below of=Test] (Test) {Test with $T_{exp}$};
    \node [decision, below of=Calibrate, node distance=3cm] (Decide) {Correlated?};
    \node [block, below of=Decide] (Validate) {Validate model};
    \node [cloud, below of=Decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {STOP};

     % Draw edges
    \path [line,dashed] (start) -- (Solve);
    \path [line] (Solve) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (SolveT);
    \path [line] (identify) -| (Experiment);
    \path [line] (SolveT) -- (Compare);
    \path [line] (Experiment) |- (Compare);
    \path [line] (Compare) -- (Calibrate);
    \path [line] (Calibrate) -- (Test);
    \path [line] (Update) -- (Calibrate);
    \path [line] (Test) -- (Decide);
    \path [line] (Decide) -| node {No}(Update);
    \path [line] (Decide) -- (Validate)
    \path [line,dashed] (Validate) -- node {Yes}(stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The research design's process conceptual diagram}
\label{The research design's process conceptual diagram}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\node [block, below of=Test] (Test) {Test with $T_{exp}$};` seems weird. You are trying to put the block `Test` below itself.

Comment: Thank you. It's done